# Need to be schooled: declaration ‘void encrypt(char*, int)’ has a different exception specifier'

Tags: c++, exception, throw

I am implementing a Caesarian cipher program. I started doing it in C, hence why I use a lot of standard C functions. However, when I realized that messages to be encrypted are truncated after the first space. So I resorted to some C++ functions.

Trouble is, when I did that, suddenly, I got the following g++ error:

```
> g++ -o cipher cipher.cc
cipher.cc: In function ‘void encrypt(char*, int)’:
cipher.cc:47:37: error: declaration of ‘void encrypt(char*, int)’ has a different exception specifier
cipher.cc:18:6: error: from previous declaration ‘void encrypt(char*, int) throw ()’
```

Here are the relevant parts of the program:

```
int key; // cipher key
char message[1000]; // 2^32

void encrypt(char message[], int key);
void decrypt(char message[], int key);

int main()
{
    string input;  
    cout<<"Enter your message: "<<endl;
    getline(cin,input);
    char* msgPtr = new char[input.length()+1];
    strcpy(msgPtr, input.c_str());

    for(int i=0; i<input.length()+1; i++) {
        message[i] = msgPtr[i];
        cout << message[i] << endl;
    }

//    printf("Enter message: ");
//    scanf("%s", message);

    printf("\nEnter Cipher Key: ");
    scanf("%d", &key);

    encrypt(message, key);
    printf("\nCiphertext: %s", message);

    decrypt(message, key);
    printf("\n\nDecrypted message: %s\n\n", message);

    return 0;
}

void encrypt(char message[], int key) 
{
    int i = 0;
    if((key % 94) == 0)
        key = rand() % 126+33;

    while (message[i] != '\0') {
        message[i] = message[i] + key; 
        i++;
    }
}
```

Added the **cout << message[i]** bit to debug, in case I don't get memory addresses instead of the actual values.

My question is this: what precisely does this compiler error mean and how does it relate to what I am attempting to do with my program? This works fine when I don't use a string. However, when I try to use a string to input the message and convert it to a char[], that is when I got this compiler error.

Comment: One signature of that function has a `throw()` and the other doesn't.

Comment: The code that you're showing doesn't seem to explain the error message. Can you copy lines 47 and 18 into your question and mark which is which?

Comment: Wait, your logic in C is wrong, so you switch to C++. That doesn't sound right. And if you switch, why not use the facilities C++ provides, like making the encryption function operate on a `std::string` instead of that memory leak you currently have?

Comment: @templatetypedef line 47 only contains closing curly brace for int main(). Line 18 is the encrypt() declaration.

Comment: @chris Could you clarify what you mean? The declaration and definition are exactly the same as far as I can tell.

Comment: @baph0mt, I'm just going by what the compiler's saying. Whatever's on line 18 on cipher.cc is different.

Comment: @chris It seems to think my encrypt() declaration has throw() appended to it. But it doesn't.

Comment: Are you including some header that maybe also declares an `encrypt()` function? As is, the code in the question doesn't reproduce the problem for me.

Comment: @sth, Not likely. The compiler points to the cc file.

Comment: @sth Your suggestion worked. Please post an answer and I'll give you rep. Changed encrypt() to encrypt2() and it worked no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are including some header that also declares an `encrypt()` function with a different signature than your local declaration.

Comment: Thanks! Not sure which header file the duplicate encrypt() is in. If you know. <cstdlib>, <cstdio>, <iostream>, <string>